# How to display data in MySQL database in a html table using php

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

Basically as it says in the question i am trying to take data from my database and have each row in the database display in a new row in a HTML table. I thought i was on the right track but when viewing my code in PhpStorm it throws up an error saying required parameter $query missing. I'm not sure where this parameter is meant to be but the error is showing up on the query line: 
$result = mysqli_query(....

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="sortable">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Project title</th>
                                <th>Start Date</th>
                                <th>Acc Manager</th>
                                <th>Designer</th>
                                <th>Stage</th>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
<?php
      function list_projects() {

          global $connection;

      $output = "";
      $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY project_title ASC");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $output .= '
      <tr>
      <td>' . $row['project_title'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['start_date'] . '</td>                                                   
      <td>' . $row['acc_manager'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['designer'] . '</td>
      <td>' . $row['stage'] . '</td>                                    
      </tr>';
      }

      return $output;

     }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are actually on the right track you just have a typo in your code msqli_fetch_array( should be mysqli_fetch_array( , you're missing a `y` and mysqli_query first parameter should be $link, so your query should be like this `mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY project_title ASC");`

Comment: Look at the parameters: http://us2.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: As a sidenote, it would also be good to return an array of rows, not a string. This way you dont couple you data access with view logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query). `mysqli_query` takes 2 parameters when used in a procedural style. I'm assuming `$connection` is your mysqli link Try:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY project_title ASC");
```

Comment: As above thanks, yes this sorted out the error, however despite having no errors none of my data is being callled and displayed on the page

Comment: Make sure the query returns something. Also, I don't see any markup for the actual table. Just the table rows and columns. Where is the rest of your HTML?

Comment: I've added in the rest of the html for the table. I had dummy content in and it was all displaying fine obviously so i know its not my HTML markup its obviously my PHP

Comment: I don't see you ever calling the function. Either remove the code from the function or put the function somewhere else, call it and store it in a variable and echo the variable where your function is now.

Comment: Thank you, i moved the function to my functions.php file and did as you said echoing the stored variable and this has worked! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `$connection` into you `mysqli_query()` function.

https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Comment: Thanks that actually got rid of the error! Even so though none of the data is being displayed when i load the page :( Don't know what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: first thing to check, make sure your query actually returns data (stupid error I've run into many times). run your query in PHPmyAdmin directly on your db.

Comment: try calling `$result->num_rows`. should return a positive int if you have results in your query

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the function?

```
echo list_projects();
```

(I know, silly question, but I dont see that you are doing it?)