# How to display data from database in table rows with php or any other scripting language

Tags: php, dreamweaver

i am still new in this php and mysql thing. I want to display data in tables which i already    designed using php programming language or any scripting language but php will be my server side  language. Thanks to those willing to help.!

Comment: Have you done any research so far?

Comment: You can find this topic very helpful. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999213/how-to-display-data-in-mysql-database-in-a-html-table-using-php)

Comment: yes i have done but only can find posting tables with php. But i dont want to post the whole script just want to post data only and allow creation of rows

Comment: Thanks to those who helped i now have better knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn how to set up a database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-database.html

You will have to learn how to apply php to use that database: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

You will have to learn html to make your page display on a page: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp